# How to know whether a random effect or a cluster effect is necessary for a mixed effect logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, random-effects-model, cluster-sample

I have 8 variables in my model out of which I have a group which is definitely not a fixed effect. I tried checking the random effect on the basis of the log-likehood test and it seems significant. I am not sure how to determine whether it is a cluster effect or the random effect. Please help me understand these two concepts.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a cluster effect and by a random effect in your context? Alternatively, maybe you can add more concrete specifics to your question - it is too vague to answer as it is at the moment.

Comment: marginal_model <- coxph(surv(time,status)~age +cluster(inst),data = lung)                         #this is with the cluster effect                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                      conditional_model <- coxme(surv(time,status)~ age+ (1|inst),data=lung)                               #this is the random effect